# find_if function build problems

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to build the following block of code in a 1-file .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class test
{

public:

    int a[10];
    int index;

    test();
    ~test();
    bool equals(int p);
    void search();
};

test::test()
{
    int temp[10] = {4, 9, 5, 6, 9, 10, 9, 255, 60, 0};

    memcpy(a, temp, sizeof(temp));

    index = -1;
}

bool test::equals(int p)
{
    return p == 9;
}

void test::search()
{
    int* p = std::find_if(a, a+10, &test::equals);
    while (p != a+10)
    {
        cout<< *p;
        index = p - a;
        p = std::find_if(p+1, a+10, &test::equals);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    test object;

    object.search();

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error as shown below, and I'm not sure exactly what's happening when I use the find_if function in a member method of a class, and I'm getting this error whenever I am doing so.

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\algorithm(87) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\algorithm(96) : see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::_Find_if(_InIt,_InIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=int *,
1>            _Pr=bool (__thiscall test::* )(int)
1>        ]
1>        c:\testprogram\nomfc\main.cpp(32) : see reference to function template instantiation '_InIt std::find_if(_InIt,_InIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _InIt=int *,
1>            _Pr=bool (__thiscall test::* )(int)
1>        ]
```

Comment: To create a code block, indent 4 spaces, or hit the button with the 1's and 0's on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_if` function expects an object which is callable as a function with no parameters. This is something like a free function, a function object or a static class function. You passed in the address of the `equals` member function which is none of these. You could resolve this by making the `equals` function a free function or a static function, since it does not require any members of the `test` instance.

```
// static
class test
{
  public:
    static bool equals(int p); // etc
};
int* p = std::find_if(a, a+10, &test::equals);

// free
bool equals(int p)
{
    return p == 9;
}
int* p = std::find_if(a, a+10, equals);
```

If your real code example requires that it be a member function, then you need to pass in a function object that acts as a closure over the class instance. I favour using the Boost bind method for this, but there are other methods as well.

```
int* p = std::find_if(a, a+10, boost::bind(&test::equals, this, _1));
```

Comment: Should the equals() function declaration in the class definition contain "int p" as the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

`test::equals` is a member function, which has different pointer syntax from an ordinary function pointer. In particular, to call it, `find_if` would need an object of type `test`, which it doesn't have (it won't, for example, automatically call it on `this`, which I'm guessing is what you have in mind).

You can move the function `equals` outside the class `test`, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p = find_if(a, a+10, bind1st(mem_fun(&test::equals), this));
```

Or better yet, get rid of that `test::equals()` member function and then

```
int *p = find_if(a, a+10, bind2nd(equals(), 9));
```

where equals is in fact `std::equals()`, a binary functor defined in header `<functional>`.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to `find_if` must be a (pointer to a) function or functor taking one argument, not a (pointer to an) instance-method which is what you're using. For example, an appropriate functor might be (loosely adapted from [this thread][1]):

```
template <typename PType, typename ArgType>
class is_good_test : unary_function<PType, bool>
{ public:
is_good_test(const ArgType & arg) : _val(arg) { }
~is_good_test() { }

bool operator()(const PType p) const
{
return p->equals(_val);
}

private:
ArgType _val;
};
```

which lets you do calls like:

```
std::find_if(a, a+10, is_good_test<test*, int>(10))


  [1]: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t288980-functors-and-stl-findif.html
```

Comment: It doesn't look quite right - you have "val" sometimes, and "_val" other times, then you have the wrong parenthesis type for the template instantiation in the find_if line.